# Is there a repository containing `protoc-gen-grpc-go` artifact?

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc

I would like to compile my grpc/proto files using gradle. *Java*, *Kotlin* (protobuf & gRPC) works perfectly. For *Go*, I am only able to compile *protobuf* without the *gRPC* part. The **protoc-gen-go** plugin seems to be available by the protoc artifact. However, I couldn't find any information about getting the gRPC-go-plugin by adding a dependency to my build.gradle.

Any hint is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

gRPC support was removed from `protocol-gen-go` in v1.20.0 according the the release notes:

> The v1.20 protoc-gen-go does not support generating gRPC service definitions. In the future, gRPC service generation will be supported by a new protoc-gen-go-grpc plugin provided by the Go gRPC project.
>
> The github.com/golang/protobuf version of protoc-gen-go continues to support gRPC and will continue to do so for the foreseeable future.

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/releases/tag/v1.20.0#v1.20-grpc-support

Two alternatives are provided.

1. Install `protocol-gen-go-grpc` from https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go.

```
go get -u google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
```

2. Install `protocol-gen-go` from github.com/golang/protobuf (as opposed to the one github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go).

```
go get -u github.com/golang/protobufv/protoc-gen-go
```

However the second choice isn’t recommended because that modules has been effectively deprecated.

> It has been superseded by the google.golang.org/protobuf module, which contains an updated and simplified API, support for protobuf reflection, and many other improvements. We recommend that new code use the google.golang.org/protobuf module.

Those `go get` commands might need to be altered for gradle support.

Comment: Thank you! This helps. I will try to trigger the `go get` from gradle to get things working.